# Why use Pip or PyPI when you can just run the setup.py file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a novice Python user and not a CS by training but I have successfully managed to download several packages (as eggs, wheels, tar and gz files).

and get them installed by using 7-Zip expose the `setup.py` file, navigating to the `setup.py` via the command shell to get the packages installed.

I see lots of posts and videos about using `PyPI` or pip to handle the installation process but wonder why should I bother if I have a method that works.

What are the advantages to using `PyPI` or `pip` other than saving a few keystrokes?

Keep in mind that I do work behind a digital curtain imposed by the IT staff, I do not have admin privileges on my computer, and little or no access to the system settings.

I'm on Windows 7 and I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: If you have used Linux and package manager, you would like the `pip`.

Comment: So, let's say you have done this for a dozen of packages you need. A few weeks later you'd like to check & update all those packages. Do you really want to manually download and extract them all over again? In addition, `pip` checks and installs dependencies as well - you really don't want to do that manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pip is a package management system used to install and manage software packages written in Python.

It is not just for saving some key-strokes, but it installs , updates and manages the packages in to one's environment. 
If tou are new to it try some commands like:

```
pip freeze : this will list all the installed packages
pip install PackageNameHere --upgrade : To upgrade existing packages
```

Lot more are their, like you can update all package at the same time .
These are just examples, and Obviously you might have heard ,
 **When you are in rome do like romans** .